# NextJS - Set dynamic environment variables at the start of the application

Tags: environment-variables, client-side, next.js

In our implementation process we created a single building and went through the different stages (integration, staging and production). In each of the environments, we have variable environmental differences.

The problem is that when we started the server it only referred to the environment variables on the server, but in the client the process.env file is empty.

stack: "next": "5.0.0" "babel-plugin-inline-dotenv": "1.1.1",

for load .env file is used "inline-dotenv"

Comment: From next@5.1.0 you can use https://github.com/zeit/next.js#exposing-configuration-to-the-server--client-side

Answer (score 7):

You can use `publicRuntimeConfig` in your next.config.js file.

Example:

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  serverRuntimeConfig: { // Will only be available on the server side
    mySecret: 'secret'
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: { // Will be available on both server and client
    staticFolder: '/static',
    mySecret: process.env.MY_SECRET // Pass through env variables
  }
}
```

note that the value of `publicRuntimeConfig.mySecret` is now getting fetched from the environment variables.
So now you can read that value by importin `next/config`

Example:

```
import getConfig from 'next/config';

const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();
console.log(publicRuntimeConfig.mySecret);
```

source: [next.js docs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#exposing-configuration-to-the-server--client-side)

Comment: This unfortunately no longer works with the current version (12) of Next, because they replace `process.env.*` with the actual value at build time.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a lot with this, because I can not afford building docker images for each environment like qa, stage, production and so on. So, I created the following npm package. Please check, maybe it will save many hours of life for someone: [next-config-env-variables-patch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-config-env-variables-patch)